# Problem in Uploading a Bootloader to Atmega8A

Tags: bootloader

I am getting an error while Uploading the Bootloader to Atmega8A
I am selecting..

```
  Board -> Arduino NG and Older
  Processor -> Atmega8A
  Programmer -> USBasp
```

and sketch code is ArduinoISP, After selecting port then I do "Burn Bootloader"

But getting an error of...

```
   "efuse" memory type not defined for part "ATmega8"
    Error while burning bootloader.
```

Please tell me what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Programmer "AVRUPro+" for Uploading Program. I downloaded its Software "Progisp" Then I did some few steps....

1) After downloading it, Run the Progisp.exe file.
2) Then went to Command tab, and clicked “Program Fuse”, It just did my fuse  set.
3)Then I just did the simple process of burning the bootloader to my Atmega Controller.
4)After this I was able to upload my program to my new Atmega Controller.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend!!!
Apparently this is a known regression [bug](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/2075) not yet corrected. The possible solution is also suggested there by user [rigelinorion](https://github.com/rigelinorion) and here is the quote:

```
Hello, I solved it this way...

Open for edit the file C:\Program Files\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\platforms.txt
this is standard section uploader/programmers tools

#==============================================================================
tools.avrdude.cmd.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude
tools.avrdude.config.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf
tools.avrdude.cmd.path.linux={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avrdude
tools.avrdude.config.path.linux={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf

tools.avrdude.upload.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude.upload.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude.upload.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {upload.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{upload.protocol} -P{serial.port} -b{upload.speed} -D "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"

tools.avrdude.program.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude.program.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"

tools.avrdude.erase.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude.erase.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude.erase.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {erase.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} -e -Uefuse:w:{bootloader.extended_fuses}:m -Ulock:w:{bootloader.unlock_bits}:m -Uhfuse:w:{bootloader.high_fuses}:m -Ulfuse:w:{bootloader.low_fuses}:m

tools.avrdude.bootloader.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude.bootloader.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude.bootloader.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {bootloader.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{runtime.ide.path}/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/{bootloader.file}:i" -Ulock:w:{bootloader.lock_bits}:m
#==============================================================================

create a new tool called, for example, avrdude1
simply copy section tools.avrdude and name it tools.avrdude1
the trick is that we remove switch "-Uefuse:w:{bootloader.extended_fuses}:m" from "tools.avrdude1.erase.pattern="

#=============================================================================
tools.avrdude1.cmd.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude
tools.avrdude1.config.path={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf
tools.avrdude1.cmd.path.linux={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avrdude
tools.avrdude1.config.path.linux={runtime.ide.path}/hardware/tools/avrdude.conf

tools.avrdude1.upload.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude1.upload.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude1.upload.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {upload.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{upload.protocol} -P{serial.port} -b{upload.speed} -D "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"

tools.avrdude1.program.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude1.program.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude1.program.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {program.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{build.path}/{build.project_name}.hex:i"

tools.avrdude1.erase.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude1.erase.params.quiet=-q -q

#this line was edited
tools.avrdude1.erase.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {erase.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} -e -Ulock:w:{bootloader.unlock_bits}:m -Uhfuse:w:{bootloader.high_fuses}:m -Ulfuse:w:{bootloader.low_fuses}:m

tools.avrdude1.bootloader.params.verbose=-v -v -v -v
tools.avrdude1.bootloader.params.quiet=-q -q
tools.avrdude1.bootloader.pattern="{cmd.path}" "-C{config.path}" {bootloader.verbose} -p{build.mcu} -c{protocol} {program.extra_params} "-Uflash:w:{runtime.ide.path}/hardware/arduino/avr/bootloaders/{bootloader.file}:i" -Ulock:w:{bootloader.lock_bits}:m
#==============================================================================

Here is an example of the use of the tool avrdude1 in boards.txt file

atmega8.name=ATmega8 OPTIBOOT
atmega8.upload.protocol=arduino
atmega8.upload.maximum_size=7168
atmega8.upload.speed=115200
atmega8.upload.tool=avrdude1
atmega8.bootloader.low_fuses=0xbf
atmega8.bootloader.high_fuses=0xCC
atmega8.bootloader.path=atmega8
atmega8.bootloader.file=optiboot/optiboot_atmega8.hex
atmega8.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
atmega8.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F
atmega8.bootloader.tool=avrdude1
atmega8.build.mcu=atmega8
atmega8.build.f_cpu=16000000L
atmega8.build.core=arduino
atmega8.build.variant=standard
```

Comment: If it's a regression bug, you could also try using an older version of the Arduino IDE.

Comment: @Gerben, yes indeed, a valid solution too. However I would probably stick with this solution because this is a minor issue compared to maybe a lot of bugs or improvements done in new IDE's.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I got it, Actually there was the fuse bit problem.

Comment: @Naveen Thats great. Post your solution here and mark it as answer because it may help others too.